# Globaly registered Vue components highlighting - WebStorm\PhpStorm

Tags: vue.js, phpstorm, nuxt.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am wondering if maybe anyone knows if it's possible in any way to highlight globally registered components in Vue\Nuxt project?

I've read about this thingy `https://github.com/JetBrains/web-types`. The issue now is that components are highlighted, but nothing is happening when I am clicking on them. (should redirect to source though)

[image]

Or maybe there is any other way to highlight globally registered components?

Please help, I'm desperate

---

EDIT

By highlighting I mean, whenever I am using the components in any other place I want it to be 'clickable'. In other words, I want to make IDE know in which file the component is implemented.

On the print screen, you can see that two components `FormField` and `FormInput` are marked. IDE is telling me that these are `unknown HTML tags`. FormInput and FormField are globally registered Vue components

`VueButton` though is working just fine because I imported it in this particular file.

I can just click `VueButton` tag and go straight to it's declaration. I want exactly the same for globally registered components

[image]

Comment: How exactly and where would you like them to be highlighted?

Comment: Thanks! It looks like this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42655